# Biburl cannot take % symbol in url

Tags: bibtex

i am trying to quote from this url `http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2009/11/what-is-xrm-how-crm-software-can-track-more-than-just-%E2%80%9Ccustomers%E2%80%9D/`, but because of % symbol, latex is telling that something is wrong.

I have also tried to escape %, result was: `http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2009/11/what-is-xrm-how-crm-software-can-track-more-than-just-\%E2\%80\%9Ccustomers\%E2\%80\%9D/`,
but it still did not work.

Can you please tell me how to solve it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

- File `percbib.tex`:

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt]{article}
  \usepackage{url}
  \begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{plain} 
  \bibliography{percbib}
  \end{document}
  ```
- File `percbib.bib`:

  ```
  @Misc{entry,
    author = "Some author",
    title = "Some title",
    year = 2013,
    howpublished = "\url{http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2009/11/what-is-xrm-how-crm-software-can-track-more-than-just-%E2%80%9Ccustomers%E2%80%9D/}"
  }
  ```